# Excluding rows derived from case statement with a specific value based on values from another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How do I exclude rows with a specific value in a field based on specific values of another field? To dive deeper:

I have a column called "rule_name" that's derived from a case statement.

I have another column called "DeliveryTermsIdentifier" that's pulled from another table (see image of query result below).

I'm trying to remove rows with rule_name **"Delivery event required"** *only if* DeliveryTermsIdentifier is "PP", "DA", ect. I'm getting thrown off because my rule_name column is based off a condition already.

[image of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0hDa.png)

Here is the SQL used to derive those 2 columns:

```
  ,case when s.ShipmentNo is not null then cast(dqr.rulename as varchar(30))
        else cast(dqc.dataqualityruleid as varchar(30)) end as rule_name

  ,case when (dqd.SuccessFlag = 0) then 'Missing'
        when (dqd.SuccessFlag = 1) then 'Reported'
        when (s.ShipmentNo is null) then 'Missing' end reporting_result

  ,s.DeliveryTermsIdentifier

from CustomerMasterList cml

join organization o on o.organizationid = cml.senderid
inner join DataQualityConfig dqc on dqc.DomainId = cml.DomainID
left outer join shipment s on s.shipmentno = cml.shipmentno
left outer join dataqualityresult dqd on dqd.shipmentid = s.shipmentid 
left outer join dataqualityrule dqr on dqr.dataqualityruleid 
=dqd.dataqualityruleid
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put what you have in a subquery and filter out with a where clause in the outer query. E.g.

```
SELECT rule_name, reporting_result, DeliveryTermsIdentifier
FROM
  (SELECT 'X'
  ,case when s.ShipmentNo is not null then cast(dqr.rulename as varchar(30))
        else cast(dqc.dataqualityruleid as varchar(30)) end as rule_name

  ,case when (dqd.SuccessFlag = 0) then 'Missing'
        when (dqd.SuccessFlag = 1) then 'Reported'
        when (s.ShipmentNo is null) then 'Missing' end reporting_result

  ,s.DeliveryTermsIdentifier

  from CustomerMasterList cml

  join organization o on o.organizationid = cml.senderid
  inner join DataQualityConfig dqc on dqc.DomainId = cml.DomainID
  left outer join shipment s on s.shipmentno = cml.shipmentno
  left outer join dataqualityresult dqd on dqd.shipmentid = s.shipmentid 
  left outer join dataqualityrule dqr on dqr.dataqualityruleid 
  =dqd.dataqualityruleid ) AS sub
WHERE DeliveryTermsIdentifier NOT IN ('PP', 'DA') AND rule_name <> 'Delivery event required'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also encapsulate your case statements into an outer apply and use the alias like this:

```
SELECT * ,
   rules.rule_name ,
   RESULT.reporting_result ,
   s.DeliveryTermsIdentifier
FROM   CustomerMasterList cml
   JOIN organization o ON o.organizationid = cml.senderid
   INNER JOIN DataQualityConfig dqc ON dqc.DomainId = cml.DomainID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN shipment s ON s.shipmentno = cml.shipmentno
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dataqualityresult dqd ON dqd.shipmentid = s.shipmentid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dataqualityrule dqr ON dqr.dataqualityruleid = dqd.dataqualityruleid
   OUTER APPLY (   SELECT CASE WHEN ( dqd.SuccessFlag = 0 ) THEN 'Missing'
                               WHEN ( dqd.SuccessFlag = 1 ) THEN 'Reported'
                               WHEN ( s.ShipmentNo IS NULL ) THEN 'Missing'
                          END reporting_result ) RESULT
   OUTER APPLY (   SELECT CASE WHEN s.ShipmentNo IS NOT NULL THEN
                                   CAST(dqr.rulename AS VARCHAR(30))
                               ELSE
                                   CAST(dqc.dataqualityruleid AS VARCHAR(30))
                          END AS rule_name ) rules
WHERE  s.DeliveryTermsIdentifier NOT IN ( 'PP', 'DA' )
   AND rules.rule_name <> 'Delivery event required';
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my explanation.  I do not want to exclude all rows with DeliveryTermsIdentifier in 'PP', 'DA' and rule_name in 'Delivery event required.' I am trying to exclude the 'Delivery event required' row for every DeliveryTermIdentifier in 'PP', 'DA'. Basically, all rows with 'PP', 'DA' should still exist, but the 'Delivery event required' should not be included for rows with DeliveryTermsIdentifier in 'PP', 'DA'